# Emacs on Windows sets DISPLAY to w32

Tags: microsoft-windows, environment

I stumbled upon the fact that Emacs on Windows sets the environment variable `DISPLAY` to `w32` (if the variable is not already set). This causes problems for example with OpenSSH.

What is the use case for setting DISPLAY? Something within Emacs or is it meant for external applications only? Is there an example app that behaves differently?

Can I safely delete the environment variable? (I know I can do this with `(setenv "DISPLAY")`).

Note: I use native Emacs build emacs-27.0.50-snapshot-2019-09-18-x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar problems.  I ended up leaving the `DISPLAY` variable at w32.  In my user environment I set `GIT_SSH=C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`.  In Emacs `~/.emacs` I unset that: `(setenv "GIT_SSH")`.

I don't know why it works, now I can `ssh-add` from a cmd prompt and vscode works with the agent, and magit works with the agent.  I did not specify an sshCommand in `~/.gitconfig`.